# Microsoft Authentication Library [MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig] is not found

Tags: swift, azure-ad-msal

I have installed [Microsoft Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) using pods. I have it successfully importing in my Swift file however it is not finding all objects.

I am trying to follow the setup code and create an `MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig` but the object is not being found. However I know the MSAL library is installed because it can find the `MSALPublicClientApplication` and call a method on it.

Can you advise why its not able to find all the library files?

It also cannot find:
`MSALWebviewParameters`
`MSALInteractiveTokenParameters`

but it can find
`MSALWebviewType`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So oddly enough when I checked out their sample project I noticed it had .h files mine did not.

So I did another pod install and it seems it changed versions! I had not specified the version but it seems the first time I ran pod install it installed 0.2.3:

[image]

Then when I ran pod install the second time it installed 1.1.2:

[image]

However after doing this is still doesnt work I am getting different errors but I will leave those to another story:

[image]

Note: These new errors are because I am running Xcode 10.2 instead of the latest version.